# What happened to org-habits from 8.2 to 9.1?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-habit, upgrade

Orgmode's `org-habits` appear broken following the upgrade of `emacs` from version 25 to 26 and orgmode from 8.2 to 9.1 along the way.

Specifically, all of my habits don't show as habits in the org-agenda any more. Now they show as regular tasks, they cannot be hidden from the agenda view with `Shift-K`.

I have noticed the `:PROPERTIES:` drawer now need to be higher up to the heading to be effective. OK, I have moved it up: right below the `SCHEDULED:` and above `:LOGBOOK:` - that makes no difference. Moving  `:PROPERTIES:` above `SCHEDULED:` seems to render a task unscheduled thus removing it from agenda.

Is there anything else to try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine for me on 9.2.6:

```
** TODO Practice
  SCHEDULED: <2019-11-20 Fri .+1d>
  :PROPERTIES:
  :STYLE:    habit
  :LAST_REPEAT: [2019-11-27 Wed]
  :END:
```

It is hidden from the agenda view with <kbd>S-K</kbd>.

As you surmised, the order has been tightened in order to allow easier parsing: scheduling information (SCHEDULED/DEADLINE) has to come right after the headline and the :PROPERTIES: drawer has to come right after that. Reading the [etc/ORG-NEWS](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/etc/ORG-NEWS) file is recommended: it covers new things and incompatible changes. In particular, this change is described in a section called `Properties drawers syntax changes` and can currently (2019/11/29) be found on line 2039 in the file (although the line number will change when a new release is made - it is better to search for the section title).

Doing `M-x org-lint` in an Org mode buffer will find a lot of these problems.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the `org-lint` heads up! The issue was in the way `TAB` interpretation in the `:PROPERTIES:` changed! I had a lot of entries automatically converted to org-mode format and I thought using `TAB` was better for readability. This worked fine in org-mode 8.2, but apparently not any more.